# Does it matter if the `encrypt` mkinitcpio hook is included on a system without full disk encryption?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt, mkinitcpio

Can I share an `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` between two Arch Linux systems, where one requires the `encrypt` hook for LUKS disk encryption, and the other does not? i.e. will it cause a problem booting the latter when the hook is called and there's nothing to decrypt, no `/dev/mapper/luksdev` in fstab?

(I gather `cryptsetup` must be installed, but that's fine, and it actually already is as a dependency of something else anyway.)

Comment: Not a real answer, because this is not authoritative by any means, but one thing we can do is just try it: using the `encrypt` hook on a system with no encrypted devices I see an error printed to the console while booting ("Failed to open encryption mapping...", see `/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/encrypt`), but eventually the system boots regularly.

Comment: Thanks @fra-san, 'eventually the system boots regularly' was just something I was nervous to test.